# Devise - Setting the scope when authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication. How can I set the sign-in scope? For example, say I only want to authenticate the user for the scope:

```
User.where(:active => true)
```

Am I being clear? It's simple, but I can elaborate more if needed.

(I realize there is a lockable module, but my *actual* scope isn't for active users, it's more like current_site.users, where the current_site is based off the domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use default_scope... but that might get in your way.

Why not override devise's `find_for_database_authentication` method? See [the wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki).

Comment: The link to the wiki is broken. This is why you need to include the actual code in your answer. The answer by @cache.zero is better.

Answer (score 15):

Just overwrite these two methods in your *User* model to check if the active flag is *true*:

```
# Called by Devise to see if an user can currently be signed in
def active_for_authentication?
  active? && super
end

# Called by Devise to get the proper error message when an user cannot be signed in
def inactive_message
  !active? ? :deactivated : super
end
```

And in your devise.en.yml, add the proper error message:

```
devise:
  failure:
    deactivated: "Luke, I'm your father and your account was locked!"
```